# Keep getting 429 too many requests even after waiting many hours

Tags: nest-api

I keep getting the error Blocked 429 too many requests. I have waited several hours and still get this error. Is there something wrong with my account? I am trying to set the temperature on my thermostat via a PUT request. I have made only a few calls to this endpoint.

Comment: For some APIs the rate limits are for all developers accessing a single device. Do you have other Works with Nest integrations running at the same time?

Comment: No, I think there is a daily limit rather than an hourly limit as it started working the next day.